# Vulkan render finished synchronisation without vkQueuePresentKHR()

Tags: synchronization, semaphore, vulkan

In Oculus mobile VrApi, we don't have access to vkQueuePresentKHR(), we provide a layer for each eye to vrapi_SubmitFrame2().

The vulkan example uses fences to synchronize with vkQueueSubmit() and vkWaitForFence().
It works with simple rendering, but if I use a longer rendering, it is not finished when it is displayed on the screen.

From what I understand, this is normal since the fences allow synchronization at the CPU level, but synchronization with the GPU is done with semaphores.

I can signal that the render is finished with a semaphore in vkQueueSubmit(), but I can't wait this semaphore to be signaled because vrapi_SubmitFrame2() don't use the ".pWaitSemaphores" field.

How to wait for the rendering to finish ?

*For information, Vulkan version is 1.0, but I think I can use v1.1.*

Comment: Isn't this more of a question for the Oculus API than for Vulkan?

Comment: In a way, but I thought others mobile vr api, or web vr api, may share the same synchronisation/presentation rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vrapi_SubmitFrame2` accepts a `CompletionFence`, which is an `EGLsync` object since VrApi is designed to work with OpenGL ES, not Vulkan. So there is no single-step way to have bubble-free synchronization.

The simplest solution would be to make sure that your rendering has finished before you call vrapi_SubmitFrame2. Pass a fence into `vkQueueSubmit`, wait for it to signal, and then call `vrapi_SubmitFrame2`. However, this will add latency and reduce performance (by reducing concurrency between CPU and GPU work) which maybe unacceptable especially for VR.

The more complex solution would be to create a Vulkan external semaphore using a `VK_EXTERNAL_SEMAPHORE_HANDLE_TYPE_SYNC_FD_BIT` handle type. Pass that as the signal semaphore to `vkQueueSubmit`. You can then extract the underlying sync fd with `vkGetSemaphoreFdKHR`. Create a `EGLsyncKHR` from that using the [EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/ANDROID/EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync.txt) extension, and pass that into `vrapi_SubmitFrame2` as your `CompletionFence`. This is a lot of steps, but the underlying synchronization (render complete -> timewarp start) should be as efficient as what you'd get by rendering with GLES, or if VrApi supported Vulkan natively.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to create a EGLSyncKHR with EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync, could you help please?

Comment: I can't find vrapi_SubmitFence2 (), I guess you mean vrapi_SubmitFrame2 (), but I don't see any way to pass a fence.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant `vrapi_SubmitFrame2` (answer edited). The fence you're passing is the EGLsyncKHR you created, in the `ovrSubmitFrameDescription::CompletionFence` field.

Comment: Oculus talk about ovrSubmitFrameDescription in their documentation, but I can't find the structure in VrApi.

Comment: Ahh, not sure what to tell you then -- I was just looking at the documentation too.

Comment: Thank you anyway. It seems that Oculus has removed completion fence since VrApi 1.20.